# Issue with selecting object properties with import

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm using some custom types for my reducers and action creators like this :

```
const types = {

    REQUEST_PENDING: 'ajax api request pending ...',
    REQUEST_SUCCESS: 'ajax api success',
    TOGGLE_SUGGESTIONS: '[ui] show/hide suggestions list'
}

export default types;
```

But when i try to import them in other files like this

```
import { REQUEST_PENDING, REQUEST_SUCCESS } from '../types';
```

I got this error

```
Attempted import error: 'REQUEST_PENDING' is not exported from '../types'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import "types" and use it like

```
import types from "../types";

types.REQUEST_PENDING
types.REQUEST_SUCCESS
```

Or you can export REQUEST_PENDING and REQUEST_SUCCESS as a constants

```
export const REQUEST_PENDING = "REQUEST_PENDING";
export const REQUEST_SUCCESS = "REQUEST_SUCCESS";
```

And then import it like

```
import { REQUEST_PENDING, REQUEST_SUCCESS } from "../types";
```

Answer (score 1):

If `types` is the default export anyway why not export the variables directly?

```
export const REQUEST_PENDING = 'ajax api request pending ...';
export const REQUEST_SUCCESS = 'ajax api success';
export const TOGGLE_SUGGESTIONS = '[ui] show/hide suggestions list';
```

The problem you have is that you currently have no named exports, only a default export, so you cannot import named values directly from the module.